# how to move values with null always to the end of the list regardless of the sorting direction - lodash

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sorting, lodash

I create a function responsible for sorting according to the direction that will be passed to it. I use orderBy from lodash library.

How to move null values always to the end regardless of the sorting direction?

This is the code I managed to write:

```
export interface TVProgram {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  imdb: Rating;
}

export interface Rating {
  rating: string;
}
```

```
import _ from "lodash";
import { TVProgram } from "../models/models";

export const sortProgramsByOrder = (
  programs: TVProgram[],
  order: boolean | "asc" | "desc"
) => {
  const orderBy = _.orderBy(
    programs,
    (data) => {
      if (data.imdb === null) {
        return 0;
      }
      return Number(data.imdb.rating);
    },
    [order]
  );

  return orderBy;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the clearest way to write it, but it works:

```
const orderBy = _.orderBy(
    programs,
    (data) => {
      if (data.imdb === null) {
        if (order === "asc") {
          return 11;
        } else if (order === "desc") {
          return -1;
        }
      }
      return Number(data.imdb.rating);
    },
    [order]
  );
```